# Cannot open remote file to run Xpath on it

Tags: php, parsing, xpath, html-parsing

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init("http://www.alibaba.com/showroom/black-and-white-wedding-dresses.html");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->strictErrorChecking = false;
    @$dom->loadHTML($html);
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

    $description = $xpath->query('//meta[@name="description"]/@content');
    foreach ($description as $n) {
        echo $n->nodeValue ;
    }
?>
```

There is nothing returned.. With other URLs it works okay. 
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Your XPath expression is fine. The site is doing user-agent detection and returning an [HTTP 302](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) response with the location set to the requesting IP address. Dump it to a file to take a look.

If you add a user-agent header to mimic a desktop browser the request will go through and everything will work as expected.

```
$ch = curl_init("http://www.alibaba.com/showroom/black-and-white-wedding-dresses.html");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1');
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->strictErrorChecking = false;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$description = $xpath->query('//meta[@name="description"]/@content');
foreach ($description as $n) {
    echo $n->nodeValue ;
}
```

Output:

```
Black And White Wedding Dresses, You Can Buy Various High Quality Black And White Wedding Dresses Products from Global Black And White Wedding Dresses Suppliers and Black And White Wedding Dresses Manufacturers at Alibaba.com
```

Answer (score 0):

When I inspect that page in the DOM inspector in Safari or Chrome, it says that the `<meta>` elements (and all the elements) are in the XHTML namespace (the namespace whose URI is `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`). I don't know why they're in that namespace (the raw markup doesn't specify them being in that namespace, AFAICT), but it would explain why your XPath expression isn't selecting them: It's asking for a meta element that's in **no** namespace.

To fix that, use this workaround:

```
$description = $xpath->query('//*[local-name() = 'meta' and
                                  @name="description"]/@content');
```

This will find meta elements regardless of what namespace they're in.

Or, to be more efficient, create a namespace resolver with the `xhtml` prefix bound to the xhtml namespace URI, and then use this namespace resolver with the expression

```
$description = $xpath->query('//xhtml:meta[@name="description"]/@content');
```

But the latter will only work for web pages where the `meta` elements are in the XHTML namespace.

Comment: @derp: Thanks, I'm going to have to look into that ... it's weird. It's in the XHTML namespace, yet it doesn't seem, on first glance, to obey the XML namespaces recommendation (http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/).

Comment: @derp How does HTML5 break from SGML? I thought HTML was an application of SGML.